# Android volley request error?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Please check the following image for the error.

[image: Volley Request Error.]

I would appreciate any kind of help to fix this error. Thank you so much.

Comment: what is `registerRequest`?  is it object of volley request?

Comment: what about the earlier errors `name` `age` etc

Comment: looks like a type mismatch. Its expecting a volley request object whereas you are passing another type.

Comment: what type mismatch? How can I fix this? I appreciate all the help you guys!